# Hibernate nested one-to-many associations

Tags: hibernate, join, one-to-many, fetch

I have the classes Polygon, LineString, Point with the following associations:

- Polygon - LineString is a one-to-many relationship (e.g. polygon.getLineStrings())
- LineString - Point is a one-to-many relationship (e.g. lineString.getPoints())

I want to retrieve all data related to a Polygon: its value types, its LineStrings and, for each LineString, its Points. It should be done ideally in a single query with JOIN fetch strategies.

Considering the following database fixture:

```
Polygon1
|-LineString1
  |-Point1
  |-Point2
  |-Point3
|-LineString2
  |-Point4
  |-Point5
```

The following query retrieves the LineStrings correctly. The points would be retrieved afterwards, for each LineString, which is not efficient:

```
from Polygon as p join fetch p.lineStrings as l
```

The following query retrieves 5 LineStrings (as many as Points), which is incorrect:

```
select Polygon as p join fetch p.lineStrings as l join fetch l.points
```

Nevertheless, the generated query seems fine:

```
select polygonent0_.ID as ID1_23_0_, linestring2_.ID as ID1_14_1_, pointentit4_.ID as ID1_22_2_, polygonent0_.POLYGONID as POLYGONI2_23_0_, polygonent0_.POLYGONTYPE as POLYGONT3_23_0_, polygonent0_.POLYGONDESIGNATOR as POLYGOND4_23_0_, polygonent0_.POLYGONAREA as POLYGONA5_23_0_, polygonent0_.POLYGONCOLOUR as POLYGONC6_23_0_, linestring2_.LINESTRINGID as LINESTRI2_14_1_, linestring2_.LINESTRINGTYPE as LINESTRI3_14_1_, linestring2_.LINESTRINGDESIGNATOR as LINESTRI4_14_1_, linestring2_.LINESTRINGWIDTH as LINESTRI5_14_1_, linestring2_.LINESTRINGLENGTH as LINESTRI6_14_1_, linestring2_.LINESTRINGCOLOUR as LINESTRI7_14_1_, linestring1_.POLYGONIDREF as POLYGONI1_23_0__, linestring1_.LINESTRINGIDREF as LINESTRI2_24_0__, pointentit4_.POINTID as POINTID2_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTTYPE as POINTTYP3_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTDESIGNATOR as POINTDES4_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTNORTH as POINTNOR5_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTEAST as POINTEAS6_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTUP as POINTUP7_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTCOLOUR as POINTCOL8_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTHORIZONTALACCURACY as POINTHOR9_22_2_, pointentit4_.POINTVERTICALACCURACY as POINTVE10_22_2_, pointentit4_.FILENAME as FILENAM11_22_2_, pointentit4_.FILELENGTH as FILELEN12_22_2_, points3_.LINESTRINGIDREF as LINESTRI1_14_1__, points3_.POINTIDREF as POINTIDR2_15_1__, points3_.idx as idx3_1__ 
from POLYGON polygonent0_ 
inner join POLYGON_LINESTRING linestring1_ on polygonent0_.ID=linestring1_.POLYGONIDREF 
inner join LINESTRING linestring2_ on linestring1_.LINESTRINGIDREF=linestring2_.ID 
inner join LINESTRING_POINT points3_ on linestring2_.ID=points3_.LINESTRINGIDREF 
inner join POINT pointentit4_ on points3_.POINTIDREF=pointentit4_.ID 
where polygonent0_.ID=?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On an initial glance I see that you are reusing the same alias 'p' for both Polygon and points. Can you give them different aliases?

Comment: Thanks @ddalton for your exquisite attention